# Button doesn't look activated

Tags: android, xml

I want a button to look activated (transparent) from the start.
My selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_activated="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false" android:state_activated="false">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#ef4444"
            android:endColor="#992f2f"
            android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

And the code of the button:

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/my_bg"
    android:state_activated="true"
/>
```

The default color of the button is red, so I guess the problem is in android:state_activated="true". How can I solve this?

Comment: can you share the screen shot of what you achieved with this code?

Comment: Nothing, the "state_activated" is simply ignored. By the way, I solved the issue switching to ToggleButtons and state_checked.

Answer (score 0):

please use this it will help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true"><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#2d7ebb" />

            <corners android:radius="5dp">
                <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#2d7ebb" />
            </corners>
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#2d7ebb" />

            <corners android:radius="5dp">
                <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#2d7ebb" />
            </corners>
        </shape></item>
    <item><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#55acee" />

            <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#55acee" />

            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

Comment: where is the *transparent* color ?

Comment: You can put colors according to your requirement as Top two items are pressed and foccused state or you can say that that items are executed whn you press the button and the last one is for default state when no actio is performed.:)